# add :hover state to different elem on hover of other elem

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

So, basically I want to detect when a user hovers over one element *(different div element, not parent nor sibling)* and when that hover occurs, add `:hover` to my other div element. My `:hover` of other div element state is also below via css. Below is one attempt at achieving this by manually adding that css in jQuery chaining method, but did not work at all.

```
  $('.song-thumb .hover-play').hover(function(){
  $('section.suggestedAlbums img').css('transform', 'scale(1.2)');   
    //  },function(){
    // $('.flyout').hide();
  });
```

---

```
section.suggestedAlbums img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2); z-index: 3; cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not get the `:hover` css state to work but here's what I could do

[Check out the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1j9g5v6d/3/) or look at the snippet below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.song-thumb .hover-play').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var elem = $('section.suggestedAlbums img');
  elem.trigger(e.type);
  elem.addClass('imgHover');
});

$('.song-thumb .hover-play').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  var elem = $('section.suggestedAlbums img');
  elem.trigger(e.type);
  elem.removeClass('imgHover');
});
var count = 0;

$('section.suggestedAlbums img').hover(function() {
  count++;
  $('[remove]').html('<label remove><br>It triggers the hover event(' + count + ') too.<br></label>');
});
```

```css
.song-thumb {
  background: aliceblue;
  padding: 1em;
}
.hover-play {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: green;
}
.imgHover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="song-thumb"><span class="hover-play">></span>
</div>
<section class="suggestedAlbums">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</section><label remove></label>
```

Comment: How so? Did you check the demo

Comment: Ok I updated the demo, it uses the classes shown in your code.